# Continuation character causes BC30201 error in visual studio enterprise 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to bring some very old VB.Net code back to life.
I do not know the original version of Visual Studio that was used with the code.
The following code causes an error on the build with the continuation character (`_`)

```
 GetTextBox(_alignment).Text = _
   FormatHashDigit(value.ToString, _
   "!&&&&&-&&&&")
```

If I remove the continuation character and combine into one line the issue is resolved.
I need to know how to resolve this because this is the cause of over 314K of errors in the code and I don't want to manually remove all continuation characters and combine the lines in this much code.
If I have to I will write an external routine to combine them; but would prefer to leave the code as is.

Comment: This might have to do with the version of vb.net and .net framework than the version of VS itself

Comment: Line continuation characters should be ```& _ ``` .  Perhaps a find and replace could help.

Comment: When I pasted into VS 2019 Community the underscores just disappeared. It seems the editor understands the syntax without any line continuation character.

Comment: What's the actual error message? You should have told us that at the outset. I'm guessing that it's a warning telling you that line continuation characters are obsolete. They are not required anywhere that a line couldn't reasonably end.

Comment: @B.Seberle, the line continuation character is just the underscore but it must be preceded by a space.  You may have seen it used to break up large `String` literals and that's why it was preceded by a concatenation operator (`&`) but it can be used after pretty much anything.